# Mongoose array of objects query by slug

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make a query for documents that have an array of objects like this. its a history of when a tag was added.

```
{
    "added_by" : ObjectId("58d92d8b11af264b87a8f5d4"),
    "tag" : ObjectId("58d92d8b11af264b87a8f5ed"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("58d92d8c11af264b87a8f6d5"),
    "added_at" : ISODate("2017-03-02T22:06:42.788Z")
}
```

I am not able to make the query on the slug just the `_id`

I have tried this:

```
var query = {
    'tags.tag': {
        slug: $in: ['tag-name']
    }
}
Node.find(query, (err, nodes) => {
    if (err) {
        res.status(404)
        res.send(err)
    } else {
        res.json(nodes);
    }
}).populate(['tags.tag'])
```

Here is the document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58d92d8c11af264b87a8f6d0"),
    "user_id" : ObjectId("58d92d8b11af264b87a8f5d4"),
    "uid" : "-KeG2FvL0jwkHFvOautH",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-03-02T22:06:42.788Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-03-02T22:06:42.051Z"),
    "tags" : [ 
        {
            "added_by" : ObjectId("58d92d8b11af264b87a8f5d4"),
            "tag" : ObjectId("58d92d8b11af264b87a8f5ed"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("58d92d8c11af264b87a8f6d5"),
            "added_at" : ISODate("2017-03-02T22:06:42.788Z")
        }, 
        {
            "added_by" : ObjectId("58d92d8b11af264b87a8f5d4"),
            "tag" : ObjectId("58d92d8b11af264b87a8f626"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("58d92d8c11af264b87a8f6d4"),
            "added_at" : ISODate("2017-03-02T22:06:42.788Z")
        }
    ],
    "status" : "publish",
    "description" : "some text here",
    "title" : "Anna James",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Since you store references to tags, you need to fetch the tag by slug first:

```
TagsCollection.find({slug:'tag-name'}, (err, tags)...)
```

then filter by tag._id:

```
var query = {
    'tags.tag': new ObjectId(tag._id)
}
```

or

```
var query = {
    'tags.tag': {'$in": [new ObjectId(tag._id), ....]}
}
```

if you have more than 1 tag matching the slug.

Honestly, it would be way more efficient, if you store tags directly in the document, instead of storing references.